# Three.js difference between 'objects' and 'elements'

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, three.js

This is hopefully a really simple question, but I'm having trouble getting a clear idea from the code...

What's the difference between 'objects' and 'elements' in Three.js?

For example, in `Projector.projectScene( scene, camera, sortObjects, sortElements )`. And the flags 'sortObjects' and 'sortElements' in the CanvasRenderer. I understand what they do collectively, but what's the difference between them / why are they separate flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **chandlerp** over on the IRC channel who answered this one for me:

`sortObjects` orders the objects in the scene. Then the CanvasRenderer further pulls geometry apart into individual faces. `sortElements` controls whether those faces are sorted.